# Apply KnownTypeAttribute to Object type?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0, known-types

I'm attempting to use the WeatherBug API (WSDL is [here](http://api.wxbug.net/weatherservice.asmx?WSDL)). I'm attempting to learn some things about WCF.

I used svcutil.exe to create the classes from the WSDL from the link above.

I then tried to execute the following code to test it:

```
var proxy = new WeatherBugWebServicesSoapClient();
var stations = proxy.GetStationListByUSZipCode("97211", UnitType.English, "myapikey");
```

I end up getting a `NetDispatcherFaultException`:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://api.wxbug.net/:GetStationListByUSZipCodeResponse. The
>   InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 352. Element
>   'http://api.wxbug.net/:anyType' contains data from a type that maps to
>   the name 'http://api.wxbug.net/:ApiStationData'. The deserializer has
>   no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a
>   DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'ApiStationData'
>   to the list of known types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException
>   for more details.

It appears that I should be getting back an object of type `ArrayOfAnyType` that is declared like this (generated by svcutil.exe):

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name = "ArrayOfAnyType", Namespace = "http://api.wxbug.net/", ItemName = "anyType")]
public class ArrayOfAnyType : System.Collections.Generic.List<object> {
}
```

The array looks like it should be a collection of `ApiStationData`, which is declared like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "ApiStationData", Namespace = "http://api.wxbug.net/")]
public partial class ApiStationData : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject {
```

From what I've read on various web pages, I *think* I need to add a `KnownTypeAttribute` to the `Object` class, since the `ArrayOfAnyType` is a `List<object>`. I don't think that's possible, though (or correct)...

It's also odd that the exception mentions `http://api.wxbug.net/:anyType`, but there isn't a definition for `anyType` in the svcutil generated code (which is why I'm making the assumption about the `ArrayOfAnyType`).

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KnownTypeAttribute` is used at the data contract, *not* the target type - that would be really impractical for many reasons. Check the **Example** section **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** for the application.

From what it seems in your case, the data contract doesn't know the `ApiStationData` type, so adding `[KnownType(typeof (ApiStationData))]` to your data contract should solve the issue.

Comment: It's still not clear to me where `KnownType` should be applied. The example shows it applied to the ancestor, but the ancestor of `ApiStationData` is object. Nearly all the classes generated by svctool have the `DataContactAttribute`, so when you say it should be added to the data contract, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: It should be the one containing the `ArrayOfAnyType` property, or I think it could also be the `ArrayOfAnyType` itself.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I actually thought I had tried that, but I apparently didn't. Thanks for the help. The next question which I'll probably figure out at some point is why WSDL doesn't have enough information for svctool to figure out that it was needed, or why svctool isn't smart enough to figure it out. Or, it's just a WCF thing that doesn't apply to other languages... More to learn, which makes it fun :)